# Bash script infinite loop one-line syntax

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple Bash script which reads from a file, line by line and prints it to the screen (adopted from another Stack Overflow answer).

`while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "$line"; sleep 2; done < testfile.txt`

I want to make this an infinite loop so that once it reaches the end of the file, it starts from the beginning again:

I tried adding a `while true;` / `while [ 1 ];`  / even a `while :;` at the beginning, but none of these work. Upon pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it gives the `>` prompt.

How do I make this loop infinite and maintain it as a one-liner?

Comment: If you make `testfile.txt` a proper POSIX text file (meaning it is terminated with a newline), you won't need the `|| [[ -n "$line" ]]` hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
while true; do while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do echo "$line"; sleep 2; done < test.txt ; done
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But why cant I nest `while` loops?

Comment: This is nested while loops. You may have forgotten the do/done keywords when you tried yourself.