# How can I effectively loop this bash command

Tags: bash, curl

```
for num in {6000..8995};do [[ $(curl -v  -i https://www.somewebsite.ca/54$num/ 2>&1 |grep "SOME KEYWORDS") ]] && echo "https://www.somewebsite.ca/54$num/" ;done > /var/www/html/index.html
```

I thought of adding while:true, but I'm not sure that'd work.

Comment: What does curl's option `-I` do?

Comment: @Cyrus https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-I headers only

Comment: Or you knew and wanted to point out the issue, I guess...

Comment: Testing a `curl` command individually was a good debugging approach, but it's more effective when you use the same command as in your condition instead of a different one

Comment: @BenjaminW.: You guessed [right](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63640153/revisions).

Comment: @Cyrus So since I'm not fetching any HTTP codes and/or http header stuff, I don't even need that argument, correct?

Comment: @OakDev: You can leave out `-v` (verbose), `-i` (include headers) and should leave out `-I` (headers only).

Comment: In general, `if [[ $(anything | grep whatever) ]]; then ...` is better written as `if anything | grep -q whatever; then ...`

Comment: Bigger issue: Why do you think your code _doesn't_ work now? Include the specific error message or other unwanted behavior you get _as part of the question itself_. This could be caused by, say, running bash-only code with `sh` as the active shell... but without seeing the error messages generated, we'd never know it.

Comment: Also, consider using `set -x` to enable tracing of execution.

Comment: @OakDev, ...also, we don't know what you _want_ from the minimal description currently included in the question. For all we know `SOME KEYWORDS` is a string that _should_ be found in the header, so `-I` is perfectly correct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The code works. I'm asking how to have it looped.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not looped? `for num in {6000..8995}; do` is a loop. Are you saying you want to put another loop outside of it? Then be specific: An endless loop? A loop over lines of an input file with different web servers to contact? Something else?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I mean I need to run constantly, once finished, start again

Comment: @CharlesDuffy with a 5 minutes delay

Comment: Ahh! I'm pretty sure that would make this a duplicate. To summarize so you have something to start with while I'm looking, though: Add `while true; do` at the front, and another `done` at the end.

Comment: ...with a `sleep 300` before the `done`, if you want that delay.

Comment: Already voted-to-close with a different close reason so I can't flag this as a duplicate, but among many others, [bash infinite loop one-line syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260045/bash-script-infinite-loop-one-line-syntax) applies.

Comment: exact syntax? end with *sleep 300; done* ?

Comment: Yes -- `while true; do` added at the front, and `; sleep 300; done` at the end should suffice.